# How do you determine the root device if /dev/root is missing?

Tags: filesystems, mount

On the distribution that I am using right now, Arch Linux ARM, Linux is launched without an initial RAM disk, meaning the kernel does all the work in mounting the root filesystem. This system is installed on an SD card and it has a script on it that needs to determine the device node of the filesystem that it resides on. This device node can change depending on how I boot the device up (e.g., I attach it to another device that is already running).

I am able to determine the mount point using `df -k --output=target ${0} | sed "1d"`. To determine the source device, I run `df -k --output=source ${0} | sed "1d"`. If I've booted into Arch Linux, the result of that last command spits out `/dev/root`, **which does not exist**. Sure, on some systems, udev will create a symbolic link from `/dev/root` to the real root device, but mine doesn't do that. I *could* look at the contents of `/proc/cmdline` but that stays the same throughout a kernel's uptime, so that means it isn't reliable.

When I get `/dev/root`, how can I determine the real underlying block device it stands in place for?

Comment: (1) Obviously I’m not understanding a lot of this. AFAIK, the mount point for the root filesystem is always `/` — why do you need to have a command to “determine the mount point” for the root filesystem? (2) What is `${0}` here? Why are you saying `${0}` instead of `$0`, or, better yet, `"$0"`? (3) Your question is about filenames / pathnames.  Do those change if you run `df` without the `-k`?  If so, please explain how. If not, consider leaving off the `-k`, because it’s clutter. (4) If you say `df /`, what do you get? In what respect does that not answer your question? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) You say, “the contents of `/proc/cmdline` … stays the same throughout a kernel’s uptime, so that means it isn’t reliable.”  Huh?  How is a stable value unreliable? (6) Does the output of `mount` (or `cat /proc/mounts`) ever show the information you want?  If not, slow down, stop, go back and start over. If the output of `mount` never shows the information you want, then I have no idea what you want, and probably everybody else is confused too, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and you are highly unlikely to get a satisfactory answer until you explain your requirement more clearly.  OTOH, if the output of `mount` sometimes shows the information you want, please give us an example of `mount` output that doesn’t show the information you want, and explain when you get that instead of the useful output.  (7) Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 7):

Answer from [the comments here](https://bootlin.com/blog/find-root-device/) is very simple. Just call:

```
findmnt -n -o SOURCE /
```

Provided that `findmnt` is present...

Answer (score 4):

The `mount` command will show it:

```
mount | sed -n 's|^/dev/\(.*\) on / .*|\1|p'
```

Comment: Nope! The output of `mount` is unreliable and difficult to process with a script.

Comment: The above will give you the block device the root filesystem is on ...

Answer (score 4):

I found [this blog post](https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-find-the-disk-where-root-is-on-in-bash-on-linux/) very helpful in finding root device and primary disk in Linux.

You'll need `lsblk` utility installed, which is provided by `util-linux` in CentOS/RHEL. For example, such a variant will give you the disk name of the root device:

```
lsblk -oMOUNTPOINT,PKNAME -rn | awk '$1 ~ /^\/$/ { print $2 }'
sda3
```

`findmnt` from the same package will give you actual underlying root device name:

```
findmnt -oTARGET,SOURCE -rn /
/ /dev/mapper/vg01-lv_root
```

Flag `-P` for both utilities will provide you the same information in the format, suitable for `eval` in the shell:

```
findmnt -oTARGET,SOURCE -Pn /
TARGET="/" SOURCE="/dev/mapper/vg01-lv_root"

lsblk -oMOUNTPOINT,PKNAME -Pn | grep 'MOUNTPOINT="/"'
MOUNTPOINT="/" PKNAME="sda3"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lsblk --noheadings --paths --output PKNAME $( findmnt --noheadings --output SOURCE --mountpoint / )
```

Example output:

```
/dev/sda
```

First, you use `findmnt` to find a device mounted as `/`, which is `/dev/sda2` in my case. Then, you find its parent device using `lsblk`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stat /` and inspect the device major/minor number or with the help of the `rdev` command get this interpreted automatically.

Comment: See here for various possible workarounds with problems of that method: http://free-electrons.com/blog/find-root-device/

Comment: Related:   [How to determine whether a Linux filesystem belongs to a running system or not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/61086/23408).

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming there's a file at `/etc/fstab`*

```
sudo cat /etc/fstab | grep '\s\/\s'
```

will give you an `fstab` entry to the block device mounted on `/`.

Comment: That is not reliable at all. If I was asking about `fstab`, then this might be a good answer.

Comment: Agreed, there is no less reliable source for mounted information than /etc/fstab, I never use it in any of my programs since it has nothing to do with what is actually mounted at this moment on the running system.

Answer (score 0):

**Kernel logs**

Do a:

```
dmesg
```

First, it might be explicitly given on the kernel CLI at the very start of boot:

```
Command line: root=/dev/vda ...
```

Otherwise, at the end of boot, if rootfs is a disk and not initrd / initramfs, the kernel says:

```
VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) on device 254:0.
```

so we then find that:

```
find /proc /sys -iname '*254:0*'
```

and then determine what it actually maps through with:

```
ls -l /sys/dev/block/254:0
```

output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan 30 15:59 /sys/dev/block/254:0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.0/virtio4/block/vda
```

Tested with this [QEMU + Buildroot setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/8217e5508782827320209644dcbaf9a6b3141724#qemu-buildroot-setup-getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

If you have mounted `/sys`, then you can extract the real root device from it. The basic idea can be seen in this shell one-liner, if you can grok it:

```
eval `stat / | awk '/Device:/ { $A=strtonum(substr($2,index($2,"/")+1)); printf "grep DEVNAME /sys/dev/block/%d:%d/uevent\n", int($A/256), $a%256; }'`
```

Call `stat /`, then extract the decimal device value and convert it into major and minor numbers using awk, then grep the DEVNAME field from the file `/sys/dev/block/<major>:<minor>/uevent`. Example output:

```
# Generic Linux PC
DEVNAME=sda1
# Raspberry Pi
DEVNAME=mmcblk0p2
```

This works with gawk, but not with mawk. I'm open to suggestions how to make it compatible with both.

**UPDATE**: I've added a quick Python version also:

```
import os                                                                       
                                                                                
# Fetch major and minor numbers of root directory.                                                
st = os.stat("/")                                                              
major = os.major(st.st_dev)                                                     
minor = os.minor(st.st_dev)                                                     
# Search for device name in "/sys" filesystem.                                  
with open(f"/sys/dev/block/{major}:{minor}/uevent") as f:                       
    for line in f:                                                              
        key, value = line.rstrip().split("=")                                   
        if key == "DEVNAME":                                                    
            print(value)                                                        
            break                                                               
    else:                                                                       
        print("root device not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have LVM and LUKS setup which looks like the following.

```json
$ lsblk -oNAME,MOUNTPOINT -J
{
   "blockdevices": [
      {"name":"sda", "mountpoint":null,
         "children": [
            {"name":"sda1", "mountpoint":"/boot/efi"},
            {"name":"sda2", "mountpoint":"/boot"},
            {"name":"sda3", "mountpoint":null,
               "children": [
                  {"name":"sda3_crypt", "mountpoint":null,
                     "children": [
                        {"name":"vgmint-root", "mountpoint":"/"},
                        {"name":"vgmint-swap_1", "mountpoint":"[SWAP]"}
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {"name":"zram0", "mountpoint":"[SWAP]"},
      {"name":"zram1", "mountpoint":"[SWAP]"},
      {"name":"zram2", "mountpoint":"[SWAP]"},
      {"name":"zram3", "mountpoint":"[SWAP]"}
   ]
}
```

I want to know that `/` is on `sda`. As `lsblk` can produce JSON with a bit of `jq`-fu I can be retrieved like this.

```
$ lsblk -oNAME,MOUNTPOINT -J | \
  jq -r '.blockdevices[] | . as $bd | .. | objects | select(.mountpoint == "/") | $bd.name'
sda
```